# How to customize the css for Angular Material paginator?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I want to modify the default look of Angular Material Paginator.
For example, I want to change the justify-content property to flex-start.

```
.mat-paginator-container {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-end;
min-height: 56px;
padding: 0 8px;
flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
width: 100%;}
```

What I did was- I pasted the css below in styles.css file

```
.mat-paginator-container {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-start;
min-height: 56px;
padding: 0 8px;
flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
width: 100%;}
```

But that didn't work. I also tried the css in the component's css file. But that also didn't work.
So how can I modify the css ?

**UPDATE**

Turns out that I had to use !important and it worked!. I was avoiding that that but had no other choice. Any better solutions, then please let me know.

Comment: a minimal example on stackblitz which recreates the issue will help everyone assist on this

Comment: Make sure and verify in console (inspect) whether your style has been added or still overwritten by some other class. As said by AlqbalRaj, stackblitz will help us to find where you are missing.

Comment: @AIqbalRaj for some reasons, I am only able to change the background color of the paginator. Every other css gets overridden.

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 8):

you can use ::ng-deep to change the style of `mat-paginator`

```
:host ::ng-deep.mat-paginator .mat-paginator-container{
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

**Without using ::ng-deep( for Angular 8+ )**

Turn off encapsulation of your component inside which you change the padding.

You can do this by

```
 import {Component,ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
   selector: 'example',
   templateUrl: 'example.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['example.component.css'],
   encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.None,
 })
 export class ExampleComponent {}
```

Wrap the component you want to style in a custom class. So it wont affect any other `mat-paginator` components.

Comment: sorry, Its because wrong class name. It should be `.mat-paginator` instead of `.paginator`. I had edited it in the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work (no longer works?) with AM 8

Answer (score 1):

By adding !important in css, I didn`t succeed.
So I did this in app.component.css file:

```
.mat-paginator {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
 }
```

But you might complain that probably you don`t want the paginator to be "flex". You can put the hole paginator in a div tag to make sure that it will be shown as a block:

In app.component.html:

```
  ...
     <div class="container">
         <mat-paginator>
              ......
         </mat-paginator>
     </div>
  ...
```

PS: Adding !important is NOT a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You should put `::ng-deep` before the class selector:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-paginator-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  min-height: 56px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  width: 100%;
}
```